# Run a select query from multiple tables with similar names like t103042020, t102042020, t101042020 etc.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, sql-query-store

How to run a select query from multiple tables with similar names like t103042020, t102042020, t101042020, etc.?

I have some tables
t103042020, t102042020, t101042020, t112042019, t111042019, t110042019. I want to merge the contents of these tables without using Union or Union all.

I have an example that I was using:

```
select * from t103042020
Union
select * from t102042020
Union
select * from t101042020
Union
select * from t112042019
Union
select * from t111042019
Union
select * from t110042019
```

I want to run the query without using Union or Union all, probably using a regular expression to read through similar table names with a name like '%T1%'. Is there a way of doing it except **union** or **union all**?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the only real way you can handle that, but make sure you use `quotename` to avoid an injection hole.

Comment: @DaleK Can you give more detail?

Comment: is this a one off thing ?

Comment: Google is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicTSQL = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ' UNION SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])) + '.' + QUOTENAME([name])
        FROM [sys].[tables]
        WHERE [name] LIKE 't10%'
            OR [name] LIKE 't111%'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,7
    ,''
);

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQL;
```